# reactjs background color transition when entering and leaving

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div that i want to use a background color with a transition and that transition should be applied when the background color is leaving as well.

I'm maintaining a `state` to decide when to use the background color and when to remove the background color. I want this background color to enter and leave smoothly. How can i do this in css? right now the background color just comes and goes without any transition effects.

My code

```
 <div className='current_code_div'>
   <div style={{backgroundColor: setInviteCodeStatus === 'success' ? '#b4c067':'transparent'}}>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.current_code_div {    
  width: auto;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `transition: background-color 0.5s ease;`?

Comment: ease will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it by css, please add below css to the div which you want to change background color on mouse enter.

```
transition:0.5s all;
transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.66,.22,.73,1.43);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div className='current_code_div'>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: setInviteCodeStatus === 'success' ? '#b4c067':'transparent', transition: 'background-color 0.5s ease'}}>

      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: yes it's working but only for when the color is leaving. The transition when the color is applying is not working. How to fix it.

Comment: It should work both way, try making time 2 second to feel if transition is fast & not noticeable due to other color